# Selecting rows where column value is 1 in the current row, but 0 in the previous row

Tags: python, pandas, shift, rolling-computation

I am working with a DataFrame on Python 3.8 where I try to replicate Excel calculations - a basic `if` with two criteria, one of which is referencing itself a row before.

```
Backtest['trade_price']=0
Backtest.loc[(Backtest['z_en_crit']==1) & 
             (Backtest['trade_price'].shift(-1)==0), "trade_price"] = 1
```

The second criterion seems to be completely ignored... as `trade_price` should have only one `1`

```
                           z_en_crit  trade_price
Datetime                                         
2020-10-21 11:00:00+01:00        0.0            0
2020-10-21 12:00:00+01:00        0.0            0
2020-10-21 13:00:00+01:00        1.0            1
2020-10-21 14:00:00+01:00        1.0            1
2020-10-21 15:00:00+01:00        1.0            1
2020-10-21 16:00:00+01:00        0.0            0
```

If you have any idea how to make this work and also make it faster I'd really appreciate it! Thanks!

EDIT:

Required output:

```
                           z_en_crit  trade_price
Datetime                                         
2020-10-21 11:00:00+01:00        0.0            0
2020-10-21 12:00:00+01:00        0.0            0
2020-10-21 13:00:00+01:00        1.0            1
2020-10-21 14:00:00+01:00        1.0            0
2020-10-21 15:00:00+01:00        1.0            0
2020-10-21 16:00:00+01:00        0.0            0
```

Comment: I don't think your question is explained clearly, because if trade_price is set to 0, then shifting it will also result in 0. Not sure what the second condition is trying to convey. Perhaps explain what excel calculations you are attempting to replicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking to shift on "z_en_crit" instead? Also, you should reverse the direction of the shift if you want to match on the first of the group, not the last.

```
df['trade_price'] = np.where(
    df['z_en_crit'].eq(1) & df['z_en_crit'].shift(1).eq(0), 1, 0)

df

                           z_en_crit  trade_price
Datetime                                         
2020-10-21 11:00:00+01:00        0.0            0
2020-10-21 12:00:00+01:00        0.0            0
2020-10-21 13:00:00+01:00        1.0            1
2020-10-21 14:00:00+01:00        1.0            0
2020-10-21 15:00:00+01:00        1.0            0
2020-10-21 16:00:00+01:00        0.0            0
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply! No, I am looking at the previous value of trade_price, ie at 13:00 I look at 12:00 and if it's zero it's True. Like a rolling criteria

Comment: @John Please indicate your expected output in the question and I'll be happy to edit the answer

Comment: @John I still think you should be looking at z_en_crit otherwise the condition makes no sense. Check the edit now?

Comment: Yeah you're right cs95, I had a flaw in my logic it seem. Also, is your method a numpy vectorization? ie the fastest way to do this?

Comment: @John it uses numpy.where which to my knowledge is highly vectorized. Please run the code and test it on your data.